# Autodialing software?

Tags: logging

I need to have a computer automatically call my office and maintain the telephone connection for at least 2 minutes.  The reason for  this, is I've contracted with a squirrelly VOIP provider that I can expect will have downtime about 1% of the time (and not bother to warn me).  Is there software that can operate in either of the following configurations:

- laptop with modem connection to plain old telephone network (which I could connect to home telephone line;
- App for an Android phone that would automatically dial at the same scheduled time each day?

This actually ends up saving me about 5 minutes each day that me, or member of my staff, would spend calling in from a cell phone, and adding it to a log.

Comment: It would be useful to know what operating system(s) you're talking about, because I doubt there's any solution that applies to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Dial Engine Pro using a script and running it from a scheduled task: http://www.phonedialerpro.com/#Engine

Answer (score 0):

[Warvox](http://www.warvox.org/) wasn't designed for this, but I think it could meet your requirements. 
It's a wardialing tool, but instead of using a basic pots modem, it uses an IAX trunk.

It has logging and reporting facilities, which could help you to graph downtimes.

[iWar](https://www.softwink.com/iwar/) is more basic, but maybe more scriptable. MySQL logging, modem & voip support.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the hard way for sure. If you have Cisco equipment, you can use [IP SLA](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk920/tsd_technology_support_sub-protocol_home.html) to generate voice streams and measure jitter, latency, MOS score, etc.

Comment: and Juniper has an equivalent called RPM that works fairly well, thought its not as in depth, IMHO.